# Array and priority of the element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of 20 questions and each question has a rating value between 1 to 5 has its own priority from 1 to 20.

for example:-  `quest_array=array(q1_value,q2_value,q3_value........q20_value)`

looks like `(5,3,4,3,2,5,3,2,2,4,3,2,2,2,4,3,2,5,4,3)`

and

`priority:q1_priority=1,q2_priority=2,q3_priority=5,q4_priority=10.....q20_priority=7`

I want to sort the `question` according to `value` and `priority` both.

Help will be appreciated

I have tried this till now but not getting expected result

```
$row_array=array(

                        "1"=>$row["q1_avg"],
                        "2"=>$row["q2_avg"],
                        "3"=>$row["q3_avg"],
                        "4"=>$row["q19_avg"],
                        "5"=>$row["q6_avg"],
                        "6"=>$row["q5_avg"],
                        "7"=>$row["q13_avg"],
                        "8"=>$row["q9_avg"],
                        "9"=>$row["q8_avg"],
                        "10"=>$row["q14_avg"],
                        "11"=>$row["q15_avg"],
                        "12"=>$row["q19_avg"],
                        "13"=>$row["q16_avg"],
                        "14"=>$row["q11_avg"],
                        "15"=>$row["q18_avg"],
                        "16"=>$row["q12_avg"],
                        "17"=>$row["q17_avg"],
                        "18"=>$row["q10_avg"],
                        "19"=>$row["q4_avg"],
                        "20"=>$row["q20_avg"]);
```

====>above 1 to 20 is the priority and $row is value

after that i have done  `asort($array);`

Comment: good idea.. what did you try before asking SO?

Comment: I have tried key-value pair sorting by putting the priority as a key but it did not give the correct result.

Comment: ok i will edit and put it in above question.

Comment: When we ask for your code, we need more than just an array. Where is the code containing the logic you've tried?

Comment: you can see now I have edited@MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_multisort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
array_multisort($quest_array, $priority);
```

Comment: Ok let me try this